# How to detect objects from barcode?

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation, qr-code, barcode

I am using this code to detect barcode from the Camera using AVFoundation.framework, it works well.

```
extension ListBarcodeViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            if let value = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
                print(value.stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns with digits only by default, how to convert or get object information from barcode?

Some apps on the App Store, can easily detect products, objects from the barcode. Are there any APIs I have missed?

Comment: If you want to link the code to an object, you need to come up with a 3rd-party data set.

Comment: @ElTomato I’d like to implement a feature something like this: Scan barcode (UPC example), get the result, and add to my local database (CoreData). Some recommendations?